# Function declaration as if statement condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, if-statement, syntax

Several days ago I was trying to declare a function inside an if() statement, and I tried doing it in many ways but did not manage to achieve this.

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
if(!function() { return false; }) {
    console.log("False");
} else {
    console.log("True");
}
```

Comment: You're passing an object that is not null, so the result of the condition is "True". You're not checking the return value of that function.

Comment: What is wrong in my question for the -3 downvotes? I never come here before searching on Google.

Comment: Don't make it screw up your day, it's not worth it.

Comment: @KimGysen Haha of course not, but I was just wondering :P Usually when people downvote they tell what was wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can... you just need to execute it as well.  Lookup [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) for more information on this.

```js
if (!(function() { return false;}())) {
  console.log("False");
} else {
  console.log("True");
}
```

The form a function expression takes is `function(){}`.  To invoke the expression when its declared you must change the format to `(function(){}())`

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE: This solution don't work!**

<del>This will work:</del>

```js
if((function() { return false; }) !== true) {
  console.log("False");
} else {
  console.log("True");
}
```

Comment: So differencse is '===' or '!==' instead of '==' or '!=' comparison? If I remember correctly, this also checks if the returned type is the same. Can you please explain a bit further?

Comment: The difference is the brace.

Comment: A note on this, this is checking that the function is declared and not the return value.

Comment: @Goblinlord Well this is not what I'm looking for. Thanks!